# Responding to a slack command request, and actually deserialising the response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I'm currently in the process of creating a slack app, and I've set up an API controller in my web app to respond to command requests. I've added the Slack.Webhooks package

The action in my controller looks like this:

```
public JsonResult GetInfo()
{
    var slackResponse = new Slack.Webhooks.SlackMessage()
    {
        ResponseType = "in_channel",
        Text = "Here is a response!"
    };
    
    return new JsonResult() { ContentType = "application/json", Data = slackResponse };
}
```

But upon calling the command /getinfo from the integrated slack channel, I get the following response in the channel:

```
Only visible to you
Info Bot APP  8:02 AM
{"Text":"Here is a response!","ResponseType":"in_channel","ReplaceOriginal":false,"DeleteOriginal":false,"Channel":null,"Username":null,"IconEmoji":null,"IconUrl":null,"Markdown":true,"Mrkdwn":true,"LinkNames":false,"Parse":0,"ThreadId":null,"Attachments":null,"Blocks":null}
```

Which is to say, I'm clearly getting a response, and it appears to be in the format that matches the expected response in the slack API documentation, but slack for some reason is not deserialising it!

How can I respond to this request in such a way that slack understands to deserialise the response properly?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a slack client to send the response.

You can check the source repository [here](https://github.com/mrb0nj/Slack.Webhooks) for more details and documentation.